# VBA: Copying cell value in variable range

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code, I'm having the hardest time identifying a specific cell in the variable range "rngCell". In the "If" statement, I would like to copy a specific cell in that column or row that the rngCell (the active cell is at) instead of the value of rngCell. I've tried using offset but have been failing. Example: If rngCell is at e42, I may need a value from e2 or a42.

Thank you.

```
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, resultsWS As Worksheet

lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Worksheets("FileShares").Select

j = 4
p = 1
q = 4
g = 6

Dim k&                      
For k = 9 To 50
With ws
    For Each rngCell In .Range(.Cells(8, k), .Cells(lngLstRow, k))

        For i = LBound(maxKeywords) To UBound(maxKeywords)
            If rngCell.Value = maxKeywords(i) And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                resultsWS.Cells(g, 2).Offset(j + p, 0) = rngCell.Value

            g = g + 1

            j = q + p - 5 'Used to start at row 8 and every row after
            End If
        Next i
    Next rngCell

End With
Next k
```

Comment: Please note this is only part of the code.

Comment: The code you're showing us will blow up with run-time error 91, since `ws` is never assigned. There's also no need whatsoever to `.Select` that `FileShares` sheet.

Comment: I'm also quite flabbergasted by `Dim k&`, given you're not using [type hints](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints#t=20170426200910747442) anywhere. Why not give it an explicit, named type like everything else?

Comment: @Mat'sMug       I didn't post the whole code.  Just posted what was relevant. I'll keep in mind in the future not to use type hints, since they're strongly discouraged. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rngCell` is E42 then:

```
rngCell.EntireRow.Cells(1)    '>>A42
rngCell.EntireColumn.Cells(2) '>>E2
```

or

```
ws.Cells(rngCell.Row, 1)      '>>A42
ws.Cells(2, rngCell.Column)   '>>E2
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Your 2 seconds of thinking saved me 5 hours of further headache.